# System.AggregateException in Visual Studio 2017 15.6.2

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I had a clean installation of Visual Studio 2017 and ReSharper but decided to upgrade both to 15.6.2 for Visual Studio and 2017.3.3 for ReSharper. Unfortunately now I keep on having a crash on Visual Studio with pop-up saying: `visual studio an exception has been encountered. this may be caused by an extension`.

So I disabled ReSharper but it keeps on going, and the error logs look like:

```
<entry>
  <record>1912</record>
  <time>2018/03/19 17:15:01.680</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
  <description>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---&gt; System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Classification.AbstractClassificationService.&lt;AddSyntacticClassificationsAsync&gt;d__3.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Classification.SyntacticClassificationTaggerProvider.TagComputer.AddClassifiedSpansForCurrentTree[TClassificationService](IClassificationDelegationService`1 delegationService, TClassificationService classificationService, SnapshotSpan span, Document document, List`1 classifiedSpans)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Classification.SyntacticClassificationTaggerProvider.TagComputer.AddClassifiedSpans[TClassificationService](IClassificationDelegationService`1 delegationService, TClassificationService classificationService, SnapshotSpan span, List`1 classifiedSpans)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Classification.SyntacticClassificationTaggerProvider.TagComputer.GetTags[TClassificationService](NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans, HostLanguageServices languageServices, IClassificationDelegationService`1 delegationService)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Classification.SyntacticClassificationTaggerProvider.TagComputer.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Classification.SyntacticClassificationTaggerProvider.Tagger.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.&lt;GetTagsForBuffer&gt;d__39.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;---&gt; (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Classification.AbstractClassificationService.&lt;AddSyntacticClassificationsAsync&gt;d__3.MoveNext()&lt;---&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
</entry>
```

Has anyone encountered such a behavior from Visual Studio 2017 and how did you solve it?

*Info: bug still occurs in 15.6.3*

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall ReSharper to see if it still happens?

Comment: Yes I have, though it hasn't change anything...

Comment: I was afraid that this would be your answer. I think that your problem is not at ReSharper. For somehow I think the problem is with VS. Your error is showing System.NullReferenceException:  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Classification.AbstractClassificationService. This is from code analysis tools from Microsoft. Have you tried to repair VS installation? When you create a completely new project, does the problem occur?

Comment: Eventually that's what I did, a full repair losing all my shorcuts and stuffs... :'(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Did it at least worked ?

Comment: Eventually yes it did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was kind of desperate on time - and patience - so I made a full repair on `Visual Studio` which seems to make it work fine. And then I had to reinstall `ReSharper`.

Sorry would have appreciated to spend more time to find a proper solution...